# How to run ruby on apache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache

I'm very new to `ruby` and I can run `ruby scripts` on command line easily, but I want to output my script to a browser, not just using the command line.

Your help will be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The 277 questions with the same tags would seem to indicate the answer is "yes".

Answer (score 6):

[Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/) is probably the easiest way to run Rails applications.

Comment: is there any installer package to install passenger? i'm getting error on command line

Comment: gem install passenger 
ERROR : Error installing passenger , The 'fastthread' native gem require installed build tools , please update your path to include build tools or download the DevKit from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instrucitons at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit/'


I'm already using the rubyinstaller the error mentioned, ))':

Comment: Have you got rvm setup first?

Comment: Anything for free with Apache?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend either Passenger or Unicorn, both of which are extremely popular in production environments.  Passenger is typically easier to setup.

See this blog post: 
["Install RVM, Passenger, Nginx and Rails 3 on Ubuntu Lucid Lynx"](http://www.blog.bridgeutopiaweb.com/post/install-rvm-passenger-nginx-and-rails-3-on-ubuntu-lucid-lynx/).  You can use WEBrick/Thin for development perhaps.